# Python JPEG to movie

Tags: python, image, video

I am looking for a way to concatenate a directory of images files (e.g., JPEGs) to a movie file (MOV, MP4, AVI) with Python. Ideally, this would also allow me to take multiple JPEGs from that directory and "paste" them into a grid which is one frame of a movie file. Which modules could achieve this?

Comment: `ffmpeg` built with libavfilters should be able to do this easily

Comment: mencoder also is easy enough to call using subprocess, which is how chronolapse does exactly what you're asking for (images to movie, not images to grid to movie). You could use PIL to create your composite grid images first then compile them into a movie the same way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [Python interface of OpenCV](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html), in particular a [VideoWriter](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter) could probably do the job. From what I understand of the doc, the following would do what you want:

```
w = cvCreateVideoWriter(filename, -1, <your framerate>, 
                        <your frame size>, is_color=1)
```

and, in a loop, for each file:

```
cvWriteFrame(w, frame)
```

Note that I have not tried this code, but I think that I got the idea right. Please tell me if it works.

Comment: broken hyperline to VideoWriter reference.  Might go to the openCV source, instead of 3rd party.

Comment: @EngrStudent Thanks for reporting. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

here's a cut-down version of a script I have that took frames from one video and them modified them(that code taken out), and written to another video.  maybe it'll help.

```
import cv2

fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('out_video.avi', fourcc, 24, (704, 240))

c = cv2.VideoCapture('in_video.avi')

while(1):
  _, f = c.read()
  if f is None:
    break

  f2 = f.copy() #make copy of the frame
  #do a bunch of stuff (missing)

  out.write(f2)  #write frame to the output video

out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
c.release()
```

If you have a bunch of images, load them in a loop and just write one image after another to your vid.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got into a working version of the project that got me into this question.
Now I want to contribute with the knowledge I got.
Here is my solution for getting all pictures in current directory and converting into a video having then centralized in a black background, so this solution works for different size images.

```py
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np

DESIRED_SIZE = (800, 600)
SLIDE_TIME = 5 # Seconds each image
FPS = 24

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc(*'X264')
writer = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, FPS, DESIRED_SIZE)

for file_name in glob.iglob('*.jpg'):
    img = cv2.imread(file_name)

    # Resize image to fit into DESIRED_SIZE
    height, width, _ = img.shape
    proportion = min(DESIRED_SIZE[0]/width, DESIRED_SIZE[1]/height)
    new_size = (int(width*proportion), int(height*proportion))
    img = cv2.resize(img, new_size)

    # Centralize image in a black frame with DESIRED_SIZE
    target_size_img = np.zeros((DESIRED_SIZE[1], DESIRED_SIZE[0], 3), dtype='uint8') 
    width_offset = (DESIRED_SIZE[0] - new_size[0]) // 2
    height_offset = (DESIRED_SIZE[1] - new_size[1]) // 2
    target_size_img[height_offset:height_offset+new_size[1], 
                    width_offset:width_offset+new_size[0]] = img

    
    for _ in range(SLIDE_TIME * FPS):
        writer.write(target_size_img)

writer.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it actually important to you that the solution should use python and produce a movie *file*? Or are these just your expectations of what a solution would look like?

If you just want to be able to play back a bunch of jpeg files as a movie, you can do it without using python or cluttering up your computer with .avi/.mov/mp4 files by going to [vidmyfigs.com](http://www.vidmyfigs.com) and using your mouse to select image files from your hard drive. The "movie" plays back in your Web browser.